# Type error resolving infix expression "or" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN

Tags: types, vhdl

I am having trouble understanding the error. For the most part, I understand the issue is in regard to the type of data. Why are some of my data defaulting to BOOLEAN? When it does A AND B it should return a std_logic value correct? Can someone explain what's happening?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Majority is port (
    A, B, C : in std_logic;
    Y: out std_logic);

end Majority;


architecture behavioral of Majority is
    begin
    Y <= '1' when ((A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C)) else
         '0';

end architecture behavioral;
```

Comment: `((A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C))` returns a logic ('1','0'X','U') result but `when` needs a boolean (true/false) argument. Try ((A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C))='1' (Sorry to say "try" but I use mostly Verilog exactly for the reason why this one fails)

Comment: @Oldfart omg.. I can't believe I overlooked that. I just started doing VHDL so I am bound to make noobie mistakes. Makes perfect sense though!

Comment: @OmarVazquez VHDL 2008 includes the ?? function that converts std_logic (and bit) to boolean. In some cases, eg. in if and when conditions, this function is implicitly infered, so std_logic can be used in place of boolean, and your original example would have compiled without a problem

Comment: 'Resolve' in the error message refers to 'the context of overload resolution' IEEE Std 1076-2008 12.5 (also see 4.5 Subprogram overloading). Prior to -2008 a condition was defined in the BNF in 8.1 Wait statement as a *boolean_*expression returning either True or False.  In -2008 that was changed to just expression with the inclusion of the conditional operator (9.2.8) that can be implicitly applied in certain cases (including here, your VHDL is valid in -2008). Without a conditional operator the expression type isn't Boolean.

Comment: While you could argue that the BNF definition of condition shouldn't have change (the old definition is the driving force for the implicit condition operator) the pre -2008 error devolves from operator overload (7.1 Expressions "The type of an expression depends only upon the types of its operands and on the operators applied; for an overloaded operand or operator, the determination of the operand type, or the identification of the overloaded operator, depends on the context (see 10.5 )." where 10.5 is The context of overload resolution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `and` and `or` operators returns a std_logic when an `std_logic` operand is passed to them and not a boolean (as I had thought in my deleted answer). `when`-`else` requires that the conditions are booleans.

So, as stated in the comment, you can do `Y <= '1' when ((A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C)) = '1' else '0';` to convert the expression that returns a `std_logic` into boolean so that it can be used in a when-else structure.

However, that structure is redundant. You can just go with:
`Y <= (A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C);`. The condition returns a `std_logic` so you can assign it directly.

Or additionally [with the VHDL 2008 "??" operator](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_ease/):

> VHDL-2008 introduces a new operator, ??. It ’s called the condition operator and it converts a STD_LOGIC expression to a BOOLEAN one: '1' and 'H' are considered TRUE and everything else FALSE. (It also converts BIT to BOOLEAN .)

The ?? operator is applied automatically in the when-else structure, so using VHDL 2008, your code should work.

Comment: In VHDL 2008 the ?? function would be implicitly infered, so direct comparison to '1' would not be required.

Comment: Apparently it's inferred also in when-else, thought that only in if-else.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.9 Condition operator "In certain circumstances, the condition operator is implicitly applied to **an** expression...— After when in a conditional signal assignment statement (see 10.5.3), either in a signal assignment statement or in a concurrent signal assignment statement". **An** expression *singular* is enforced by syntax, 9.1 General, the BNF, conditional_operator primary where **an** expression in parentheses (`((A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C))`) can be a primary.

Comment: `Y <= ((A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C);` While the original concurrent conditional assignment statement will map meta values to '0' and this does not. For an exact transformation `Y <= TO_STDULOGIC( TO_BIT(s => (A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C), xmap => '0'));` which with the xmap parameter default of '0' can be simplified to `Y <= TO_STDULOGIC( TO_BIT((A AND B) OR (A AND C) OR (B AND C)));` and replicates the original conditional assignment behavior. (And you could argue propagating meta values is more useful in simulation, otherwise use BIT instead).